# Firestore trigger functions not logging in local emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Firestore trigger functions not logging(trigger) in local emulator, howewer when I deploy them they logs and works fine.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase-adminsdk-.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://find-place.firebaseio.com"
});
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Function itself

```
exports.emergencyCreated = functions.firestore
.document('emergencies/{emergenciesId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  console.info('created')
  const emergencyData = snap.data();
  console.log(emergencyData)


  // perform desired operations ...
});
```

Terminal Logs

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore
+  functions: Using node@10 from host.
+  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  firestore: Serving ALL traffic (including WebChannel) on http://localhost:5004
!  firestore: Support for WebChannel on a separate port (5005) is DEPRECATED and will go away soon. 
Please use port above instead.
i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
+  firestore: Emulator started at http://localhost:5004
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:5004
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\master\Desktop\find-safe-place\functions" for Cloud Functions...
+  functions[sendInviteToApp]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/find-safe-place/us- 
central1/sendInviteToApp).
+  functions[emergencyCreated]: firestore function initialized.
+  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

Config on Vue Client

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/firebase-auth'
import 'firebase/messaging'
import 'firebase/functions'

firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
```

Package.json

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing that should trigger the function in the emulator?

Comment: On front end I'm creating a new emergencies document

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate **exactly** what you're doing.  We should be able to duplicate what you're seeing by following all the instructions in the question.

Comment: I am facing the same kind of issue. Emulator not logging the logs from firestore.
So I followed this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator, started the emulator by `firebase emulators:start`, changed my frontend code with ```const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
db.settings({
  host: 'localhost:5003', //port I added in my firebase.json
  ssl: false
});``` then added a doc to the collection. Expecting the function will get called and I see log in terminal. How do I fix it?

Comment: Hoping to replicate what's happening in the cloud function and see the same kinda log in the local terminal to make development faster.

Comment: I am still stuck with this for days now. No help?